# I don't recognize this HW address format

Tags: mac-address, arp

I'm looking at the contents of `/proc/net/arp` from a google wifi onhub's diagnostic report and the format of the HW address is confusing because it's missing a character and ends with an asterix.  Does anyone know why?

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.1.70     0x1         0x2         10bf48391ae*          *        br-lan
192.168.1.128    0x1         0x2         f0189844b16*          *        br-lan
etc...
```

For additional context, if I use the Google WIFI app to lookup the MAC for `192.168.1.70` the MAC is `10:bf:48:8d:de:5c` and the MAC for `192.168.1.128` is `f0:18:98:1e:a6:1e`.

The OUI's are the same but the last 6 are clearly different.

From the same device from the `/sbin/brctl showmacs br-lan` command I get this:

```
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
4       10bf48391ae*    no          46.92
3       f0189844b16*    no          0.57
```

Same format.

Comment: https://support.google.com/wifi/answer/6246642 - it looks like google is obfuscating the MAC in order to preserve privacy, as I believe that endpoint is what supplies the feedback mechanism for data sent to Google.